# How to pass a Rails variable into a view's CSS that must be refreshed dynamically (every 60 seconds)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a variable for the background-image attribute of an element that I need to modify every 60 seconds by some backend logic in a rails app.

**How can you get a variable or method value from a helper on into the css for a view?**

Presently I have a helper that culls a an updated URL from another source.  I need to trigger this helper call every minute in order to get an updated URL for the source image that's being masked by the following css:

```
.bg {
    background-image: url(http://mydomain.tld/someimage.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    background-size: 203%;
    background-position: top left; 
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;  
}
```

The `background-image url` is what needs to be refreshed on the minute.

Comment: Sounds like inline css would be the way to go here since it's checking/changing on each load.

Comment: To top it off, I need to actually modify it every 60 seconds.  Presently I'm using js to append a timestamp at a given interval and that's working well right now for the img src's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you can't really directly access the CSS from your view code - however you could certainly apply CSS styles using Javascript (JQuery makes it easy and ships with rails by default), and you could use an instance variable from your controller in that Javascript.

Alternately you could use inline CSS in your view - but that seems even nastier than the JS solution.

edited:

Here is the gist of what I'm talking about - this isn't tested, but should give you a start.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshImage = function(){
        $.ajax({
              url: 'your helper url here',
              success: function( data ) {
                $(".bg").css("background-image" "url(" + data.url + ")"); 
                 setTimeout(refreshImage(), 60000); 
              }
        });
    }
    refreshImage();
});
```

Basically, you can set up a call on document ready that will fetch the image url from some action that you define, then set it on your page, and "schedule" itself to fire again in 60 seconds.

Comment: Right.  I think that this is the right approach.  Particularly due to the nature of the dynamic refresh that I'm ultimately working to accomplish.

Comment: @ylluminate In that case, I'd set up a JQuery AJAX call to a json action in your controller that returns the image url that you need to display. In the "success" callback for the AJAX action, set the needed CSS value and set the same AJAX action to re-fire on a setTimeout().

Comment: If the question didn't mention the JS requirement, I'd probably have said the simple inline solution was better, but +1 for just doing it entirely with JS in this case :)

Comment: I've updated my question to add some clarity on the real intent.  I am very interested by what you're saying @thecoffman and I'd like to see more details on how you'd propose doing that given the additional details above.

Comment: Alright, yes, I think I'm getting there.  On the `your helper url here` are you referring to a controller route or otherwise?  I may need an example or more verbosity in your reply of that due to not being quite adept yet with rails.  I also placed your code into a jsfiddle to try to get to a working model to some degree: http://jsfiddle.net/ZE9L8/ - I think between that and a little more verbosity I'll be golden.

Comment: @ylluminate Basically that URL could be any url that would return JSON data structured like so { url: "background image url" }. In this case I'd probably add a controller action with a JSON respond_to block to return the appropriate information.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with CSS on the page directly, just the same way as you would for any other dynamic content on the page.